# C++ fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler with openMP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, openmp

I have a program that solves sudoku puzzles and I've gotten it to work sequentially, but now I'm trying to parallelize it using openMP. The function `solvePuzzle()` includes the algorithm and I want to parallelize the for loop within it however when I add `#pragma omp parallel for` statement before my for loop i get this error:  `fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`

The code for the function is `solvePuzzle()`:

```
    bool sudoku::solvePuzzle(int grid[CELL][CELL]) {
        int row, col;

        if (!findEmptyCell(grid, row, col))
            return true; 
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
            if (checkAccuracy(grid, row, col, num)) {
                grid[row][col] = num;

                if (solvePuzzle(grid))
                    return true;

                grid[row][col] = EMPTY_CELL;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the driver with main if it helps:

```
#include "SudokuGrid.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    sudoku sudoku;
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();

    if (sudoku.readPuzzle("1.txt")) {
        sudoku.printGrid(sudoku.grid);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect file" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    if (sudoku.solvePuzzle(sudoku.grid) == true)
        sudoku.printGrid(sudoku.grid);
    else
        printf("No solution exists");

    t2 = clock();
    printf("Time to execute = %1d ms\n", (t2 - t1));

    return 0;
}
```

Full error when built:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Sudoku, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>SudokuGrid.cpp
1>c:\users\john\source\repos\sudoku\sudoku\sudokugrid.cpp(8): fatal error 
C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 258)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near 
the locations listed above.
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>
1>Done building project "Sudoku.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: ***C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler*** Likely means the compiler has a bug. Try its advice.

Comment: And where is the line 8 of `sudokugrid.cpp`?

Comment: @Mihayl A. A  first line of the function ```bool sudoku::solvePuzzle(int grid[CELL][CELL]) {```

Comment: And what's the value for `CELL`? I hope not big?

Comment: @MihaylA.A the value is 9

Comment: @drescherjm I dont know how i can simplify the code and by changing does it mean just move stuff around or actually change logic.

Comment: Values are 1 .. 9 in sudoku. I am not sure there is an out of bounds access here since we don't have the code for findEmptyCell()

Comment: The code works sequentially and produces accurate results so there is no out of bounds happening

Comment: ***changing does it mean just move stuff around or actually change logic*** Sometimes it is just moving stuff around. Sometimes it requires changing the code. Sometimes it's triggered by bad user code sometimes it is not. Sometimes a compiler upgrade will fix the issue. If you can't figure things out try an online compiler like ideone.com to see if there are any warnings.

Comment: The problem, aside from the wrong indexing, is with the `return true;` in the loop. Make a variable and use `break;` Repro: https://godbolt.org/g/4m7xu9 and Fix - https://godbolt.org/g/MV3a3w

Comment: @MihaylA.A ah okay so i cant put a return there, I got it to run but now I guess I have to change my logic to account for that.

Comment: But looks like `break` is also not good "OpenMP requires that a loop construct processes each iteration. Breaking out of the loop (using return, goto, break, throw or other means) is not allowed." - https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/

Comment: [Breaking Out of Loops in OpenMP](http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/06/29/breaking-out-of-loops-in-openmp/) You have to change the loop to continue looping til end

Comment: @MihaylA.A I'm having trouble understanding where i should put the abort. Should it be for the whole for loop like in the example?

Comment: @MihaylA.A I figured it out thanks

Answer (score 6):

To summarize, the problem is returning from inside the parallelized `for` loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
            ...
            if (solvePuzzle(grid))
                return true;           // BAD

            ...
        }
    }
```

> "OpenMP requires that a loop construct processes each iteration. Breaking out of the loop (using return, goto, break, throw or other means) is not allowed."
>
> -- https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/

So the solution is to let the loop loop through all iterations (See also [Breaking Out of Loops](http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/06/29/breaking-out-of-loops-in-openmp/)).

```
bool solvePuzzle(int grid[CELL][CELL]) {
    bool solved = false;
    int row, col;

    if (!findEmptyCell(grid, row, col))
        return true;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
        #pragma omp flush (solved)
        if (!solved && checkAccuracy(grid, row, col, num)) {
            grid[row][col] = num;

            if (solvePuzzle(grid)) {
                solved = true;
                #pragma omp flush (solved)
            } else {
                grid[row][col] = EMPTY_CELL;
            }
        }
    }
    return solved;
}
```

[Repro](https://godbolt.org/g/4m7xu9)

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/a8A7LZ)