# fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler - openmp for parallel for

Tags: c++, openmp, fatal-error, visual-studio-2019

Upgraded to VS2019 from VS2017, and am getting this compiler error on extremely simple code lines.
The compiler indicates the '#pragma omp parallel for' line is where the fatal error occurs.
The only thing unique about this code section is that it is called by a background worker...it is not inside a background worker, but is part of code called by a background worker.

```
int N;
N = tbtc->Count/7;//the array list length
if (N > 0)
{
TBTC_CENTROIDS = gcnew array<double,2>(7,N);       
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)        
{            
TBTC_CENTROIDS[0,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7]);
TBTC_CENTROIDS[1,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7+1]);
TBTC_CENTROIDS[2,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7+2]);
TBTC_CENTROIDS[3,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7+3]);
TBTC_CENTROIDS[4,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7+4]);
TBTC_CENTROIDS[5,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7+5]);
TBTC_CENTROIDS[6,i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(tbtc[i*7+6]);

}
tbtc->Clear();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540292/c-fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler-with-openm)

Comment: Using #pragma omp in managed C++/CLI code is unwise.  Consider Parallel::For instead.

Comment: Is VS2019 a compiler? Or just a text editor? If I comment out return value lines from functions which are supposed to return a value, the "compiler" doesn't give a warning or error and it says it compiles. Is VS2019 real or just some knock off from somewhere else?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Complain to the compiler vendor!